# Receiving JSON Parse Error During AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP script that is creating my JSON needed for my web app. I am using jQuery's Ajax capabilities to fetch the JSON from my PHP page that is creating the JSON. I am finding a weird quirk though. If I simply run my PHP file in the web browser and output the JSON and then I copy that JSON into a file named `myJSON.json` which is linked to my Ajax URL call, my code works. However, If I link directly to my PHP file in the Ajax URL call, I get the following error: **`Requested JSON parse failed`**. So here is my relevant PHP Code:

```
<?php

$groupArray = array();

// Setup the beginning of the json file
$json = '
{
    "emails": [';

 // Loop through the request results
foreach ($contextIORequest->getData() as $message) {

  // `date_received` is in Unix time. Begin converting this to a readable date and convert it to the users timezone
  $newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago"); // This will be based on the users location during production
  $currentTime = new DateTime();
  $currentTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $message['date_received']);
  $currentTime->setTimezone($newTZ);
  $formattedDateReceived = $currentTime->format('F j, Y');

  // The JSON structure is organized by date (group). Each unique date will be placed in its own group in the JSON file. So we need to check if a date is already in the $groupArray. If it is, then we simply add the email data to the current date group. If the date is not already in the $groupArray, then we will need to create a new group and add the email data to the new group.
  if (!in_array($formattedDateReceived, $groupArray)) {

    // This date is not yet in the $groupArray

    // Check if this is the first group being added to the $groupArray. If it is, the first group added requires different formatting than all other groups that will be added
    if (count($groupArray) == 0) {

      // This is the first group being added
      $json .= '{
            "group": "'.$formattedDateReceived.'",
            "list": [';

    } else {

      // This is not the first group being added. Close the previous "group" and "list" objects and then create new "group" and "list" objects.

      // Before closing the previous "group" and "list" objects, we need to remove the trailing comma ',' from the last "list" item in the previous "group"
      $json = rtrim($json, ',');

      // ']' is closing the previous "list" object. '},' is closing the previous "group" object
      $json .= ']
        },{
            "group": "'.$formattedDateReceived.'",
            "list": [';

    }

    // Now we need to add this date to the $groupArray
    $groupArray[] = $formattedDateReceived;


    // The body of the email cannot have unescaped quotes or apostrophies. It also cannot have line breaks or multiple spaces between words.
    $body = addslashes($message['body'][0]['content']); // Escapes quotes and apostrophies
    $body = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),"", $body); // Removes all line breaks causing the body string to be all on one line
    $newBody = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $body); // Remove any multiple spaces between words

    // Add the email to the JSON structure
    $json .= '
    {
      "id": "'.$message['message_id'].'",
      "subject": "'.addslashes($message['subject']).'",
      "to": ["David Nester", "Jane Smith"],
      "body": "'.$newBody.'",
      "time": "'.$formattedDateReceived.'",
      "datetime" : "'.$formattedDateReceived.'",
      "from": "'.$message['addresses']['from']['name'].'",
      "dp": "assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg",
      "dpRetina": "assets/img/profiles/avatar2x.jpg"
    },';

//    echo "<h1>New Group</h1>";
//    echo "Date: ".$message['date_received']." ($formattedString)\n<br>";
//    echo "From: ".$message['addresses']['from']['email']."\n<br>";
//    echo "Subject: ".$message['subject']."\n<br>";
//    echo "Thread Size: ".$message['thread_size']."\n<br>";
//    echo "Message ID: ".$message['message_id']."\n<br>";
//    echo "Flags: ".$message['flags'][0]."\n<br>";

  } else {

    // This date is already in the $groupArray

    // The body of the email cannot have unescaped quotes or apostrophies. It also cannot have line breaks or multiple spaces between words.
    $body = addslashes($message['body'][0]['content']); // Escapes quotes and apostrophies
    $body = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),"", $body); // Removes all line breaks causing the body string to be all on one line
    $newBody = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $body); // Remove any multiple spaces between words

    // Add the email to the JSON structure
    $json .= '
    {
      "id": "'.$message['message_id'].'",
      "subject": "'.addslashes($message['subject']).'",
      "to": ["David Nester", "Jane Smith"],
      "body": "'.$newBody.'",
      "time": "'.$formattedDateReceived.'",
      "datetime" : "'.$formattedDateReceived.'",
      "from": "'.$message['addresses']['from']['name'].'",
      "dp": "assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg",
      "dpRetina": "assets/img/profiles/avatar2x.jpg"
    },';

  }
} // end foreach loop

// Before closing the very last "group" and "list" objects, we need to remove the trailing comma ',' from the last "list" item in the last "group"
$json = rtrim($json, ',');

// Complete the JSON structure
$json .= ']
        }
    ]
}';

// Output the JSON
file_put_contents('emails.json', $json);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo $json;

?>
```

So if I run this PHP file in my web browser, it outputs the JSON. I then copied and pasted the JSON into a JSON file. I then link my AJAX call to the JSON file and everything is parsed correctly. **But** I need to link to the PHP file that creates the JSON in my AJAX call. However, when I do this, I get a parse error even though it is the exact same code I copied and pasted in my JSON file that works perfectly. I am really stumped on this one. Here is my relevant AJAX code as well:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "create-json.php",
    success: function(data) {

        $.each(data.emails, function(i) {
            var obj = data.emails[i];
            var list = obj.list;

            $.each(list, function(j) {
                var $this = list[j];
                var id = $this.id;
            });

        });

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The format of the JSON is invalid. You can find out exactly where by using http://jsonlint.com . I would suggest you use `json_encode` instead of manually hacking together a string.

Comment: Don't build JSON by hand.  Instead, use a JSON serializer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But why does it parse correctly when I copy and paste the output?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors in the request?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I have and there are no errors or warnings appearing in the console.

Comment: Could you give a sample of the JSON you're returning.

Comment: @three3 if the exact same json string works when copy pasted, maybe this has to do with encoding. Is your PHP page UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @blex I did not explicitly set an encoding type in my PHP script. How would I set the encoding type to UTF-8? I will give this a try.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Here is a link to my full JSON output: http://jsfiddle.net/wee6amsg/

Comment: @blex will try that now. I just tried doing like this `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` but that did not work.

Comment: @blex I am not seeing the error. Can you please point it out to me. I have been staring at this code for hours now trying to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @blex is it missing a `}` curly brace?

Comment: JUST json_encode, ARRGHHHH!!!

Comment: @blex there is a foreach loop being run, I just did not include it in my posting. Sorry, I did not think it was relevant. I was trying to keep the code down to a minimal since there was already a lot. Do you need to see that code?

Comment: @blex I have updated my posting to include the loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a JSON string from scratch, build your data structure using associative arrays (key => value), and just `json_encode()` it, it will save you a lot of trouble on formatting.

Also note that this function escapes strings for you.

**Revised code**

```
$groupArray = array();

$json = array( 'emails' => array() );

foreach ($contextIORequest->getData() as $message) {

  $newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago");
  $currentTime = new DateTime();
  $currentTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $message['date_received']);
  $currentTime->setTimezone($newTZ);
  $formattedDateReceived = $currentTime->format('F j, Y');

  if (!in_array($formattedDateReceived, $groupArray)) {
      array_push( $json['emails'],
          array(
               'group' => $formattedDateReceived,
               'list' => array()
          )
      );
      $groupArray[] = $formattedDateReceived;
  }

  $body = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),"", $message['body'][0]['content']);
  $newBody = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $body);

  array_push($json['emails'][array_search($formattedDateReceived,$groupArray)]['list'],
      array(
        'id' => $message['message_id'],
        'subject'=> addslashes($message['subject']),
        'to' => array("Me"),
        'body' => $newBody,
        'time' => $formattedDateReceived,
        'datetime' => $formattedDateReceived,
        'from' => $message['addresses']['from']['name'],
        'dp' => "assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg",
        'dpRetina' => "assets/img/profiles/avatar2x.jpg"
      )
  );

} // end foreach loop

// Output the JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: trying it now. Will let you know in a few minutes how it goes!

Comment: You are a life saver my friend! This works beautifully. The only issue is that links in `'body' => $newBody,` do not function properly. Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/aOwjR1j

It seems this is due to the urls being escaped. Here is an example url:



`<a href="\&quot;http://www.stocklayouts.com/Templates/Brochure/Medical-Clinic-Brochure-Template-Design-MD0390101.aspx\&quot;"> <img src="\" alt="\&quot;Medical" clinic="" trifold="" brochure\"="" border="\&quot;0\&quot;" width="\&quot;620\&quot;" height="\&quot;384\&quot;" http:="" www.stocklayouts.com="" images="" superviews=""> </a>`

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Just need to remove the line `$body = addslashes($message['body'][0]['content']);`. This solves everything :} God bless you buddy

Comment: `json_encode` escapes strings for you, that was why. Always happy to help.