# Append JSON Data to JSON File Located on Server with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file stored on my server that I need to add data to. I have successfully retrieved the file into memory and have parsed it successfully. I am just having a hard time placing the new JSON data in the correct spot.

Here is the format of my JSON file:

```
{
  "emails": [

              {
                "group": "1st Group",
                "list": [
                          {
                            "id": 1,
                            "subject": "Testing 1"
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 2,
                            "subject": "Testing 2"
                          }
                        ] // End list array
              }, // End 1st Group 

              {
                "group": "2nd Group",
                "list": [
                          {
                            "id": 3,
                            "subject": "Testing 3"
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 4,
                            "subject": "Testing 4"
                          }
                        ] // End list array
              } // End 2nd Group

              /* NEED TO INSERT NEW DATA HERE */

             ] // End emails array
}
```

I am trying to append a new `group` `list` after the last `group` `list`. In this example, that would be after this line: `} // End 2nd Group`.

Here is my PHP code which gets the JSON file from my server and parses it:

```
$getJSON = file_get_contents('emails.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($getJSON, true);

$numberOfGroups = count($tempArray['emails'][0]);
```

And here is my php code that creates the format/layout of my JSON file:

```
$groupArray = array();

$json = array( 'emails' => array() );

foreach ($contextIORequest->getData() as $message) {

  $newTZ = new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago");
  $currentTime = new DateTime();
  $currentTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $message['date_received']);
  $currentTime->setTimezone($newTZ);
  $formattedDateReceived = $currentTime->format('F j, Y');

  if (!in_array($formattedDateReceived, $groupArray)) {
      array_push( $json['emails'],
          array(
               'group' => $formattedDateReceived,
               'list' => array()
          )
      );
      $groupArray[] = $formattedDateReceived;
  }

  $body = str_replace(array("\r\n","\n"),"", $message['body'][0]['content']);
  $newBody = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $body);

  array_push($json['emails'][array_search($formattedDateReceived,$groupArray)]['list'],
      array(
        'id' => $message['message_id'],
        'subject'=> addslashes($message['subject']),
        'to' => array("Me"),
        'body' => $newBody,
        'time' => $formattedDateReceived,
        'datetime' => $formattedDateReceived,
        'from' => $message['addresses']['from']['name'],
        'dp' => "assets/img/profiles/avatar.jpg",
        'dpRetina' => "assets/img/profiles/avatar2x.jpg"
      )
  );

} // end foreach loop

// Output the JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
```

So how would I go about appending a new `group` `list` after the last `group` `list`? And this needs to be done without actually included the `emails` array used to create the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `json_decode` on the serialized data (with the second param passed as `true` like you've done), you'll have, in PHP, an associative array which has one element at a key named `emails`. That element is an array and holds the group lists to which you want to add another. So it's a matter of:

```
$data = json_decode($getJSON, true);
$data['emails'][] = $TheNewGroupList;
```

Don't let the fact that it started as serialized data in JSON format get you frazzled. Once you've run `json_decode` it's just a PHP data structure (object or array), and operations on it are just like any other PHP data.

Comment: thanks for the response. My new JSON data that needs to be appended is nested in an `emails` php array. I just need to append the content inside located inside the `emails` php array. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You've provided a sample of your starting JSON. Please provide a sample of the data which needs to be appended and perhaps I'll understand you better.

Comment: I received help earlier this week on StackOverflow. This answer located here has my PHP code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310533/317740

As you can see in the code, all of the data is nested in an `emails` array. I need all of the data inside the `emails` array to be appended, but not the actual `emails` array. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. This is the kind of stuff you should have in your actual question, though. I have answered your actual question you asked. I'll take a look, but you should edit the question to include the more specific requirements you actually have so that future reads can benefit.

Comment: Sounds great. I will update it now. Thanks for the help!